# GTK window doesn't expand children according to GtkImage

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, glade

If I simply use GtkImage, the window will be resized according to the image loaded dimensions. However.. If I pass the GtkImage in scrolled area:

```
[+] Scrolled Area
 |____[+] View Port
       |____[+] GtkImage
```

The window and its children will not expand.
Which setting I have to edit in order to make the whole area expandable, according to the image's dimensions?

Comment: I can't find the technical reasons (so this is a comment) but GtkScrolledWindow has its own sizing rules so the behavior you're seeing isn't unexpected. If you want the window to change size when you load an image, you can use `gtk_window_resize()` manually.

Comment: @andlabs Yeah I know. I can use pixbuff's lib to determine width/height of image and change the window size using them.. thought, this will not be exact and dnynamic.

Comment: ..and it doesn't work with GIFs.